# jQuery flot the tooltip will not hide when I move the mouse quickly out of plot

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events, flot

Please have a look at the example of jQuery flot with tooltip, which is at http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/interacting/

When I put the mouse and move the normally the tooltip appears and disappears normally.

However when I move the mouse quickly out of plot, the tooltip will remain.

Please see below animated gif which shows slow and quick mouse movement.

[image]

The main part code which handles the hover is as below:

```
$("#placeholder").bind("plothover", function (event, pos, item) {

            if (item) {
                var x = item.datapoint[0].toFixed(2),
                    y = item.datapoint[1].toFixed(2);

                $("#tooltip").html(item.series.label + " of " + x + " = " + y)
                    .css({top: item.pageY+5, left: item.pageX+5})
                    .fadeIn(200);
            } else {
                $("#tooltip").hide();
            }
    });
```

I **think** it is because when I move the mouse quickly the `$("#tooltip").hide();` executes when the `$("#tooltip").html` is not rendered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`#placeholder`, which is the graph container, is binded to the `plotover` event.
So when such event occur on this container element, the script checks if there is an `item` returned in order to decide to show or hide the tooltip.

Now when your mouse is outside this container, there is no more `plothover` event triggered. So the script is not executed to hide the tooltip.

To fix that, I would add a script which would hide the tooltip when the mouse leaves the container like this:

```
$("#placeholder").on("mouseleave", function(){
  $("#tooltip").hide();
});
```

Also, notice that [`.bind()` is deprecated](http://api.jquery.com/bind/). It is preferable to use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

---

**EDIT**

I didn't think about delays in my first answer.
When passing your mouse fast on the chart item... There is something like a 600ms delay for the tooltip show animation.

So the mouseleve event is trigered too early to close it.

Try this now:

```
$(document).on("mousemove",function(e){
  if ( $(e.target).closest("#placeholder").length == 0 ){
    $("#tooltip").hide();
  }
});
```

So now, on mousemove, this script will check if the mouse is over the chart container on any of his childs. If not, it will hide the tooltip.

Comment: I could not find why but the `$("#tooltip").hide();` did not worked. Here are my tests: The  `$("#tooltip").htm('a Test')`; changed the tooltip text. The  `$("#chartTooltip").css({display:none});` did not hide. The `$("#chartTooltip").css({"background-color": #bee });` did not changed color. And finally the `$("#chartTooltip").removeAttr( 'style' );` worked. Any way thanks please edit so I can mark it as correct answer !

Comment: mmm... I don't see any `$("#chartTooltip")` element in the page... So I don't get it.

Comment: Ops! Yes I mean `$("#tooltip")`... It was a cut and past mistake. So only `$("#tooltip").removeAttr( 'style' );` worked

Comment: I just tryed it... And it is no good. It moves the tooltip in the footer X=0 and Y=0 position=relative.... Still visible. `.hide()` is working on my side.

Answer (score 1):

I think the explanation in the other answer is not complete:

The problem occurs because the `hide()` executes before the `fadeIn()` is finished. And at the end of the `fadeIn()` a `show()` is executed implicitly.

Using `fadeOut(1)` instead of `hide()` fixes this because the `fadeOut()` is [queued](http://api.jquery.com/queue/) after the `fadeIn()` instead of executed directly like the `hide()`.

Comment: Well the `fadeOut(1)` some how works but you see blinking when moving mouse.